# Started with Ubuntu, apt-get upgrade, now I have Trisquel?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, trisquel

I was considering moving to Trisquel (although, to be clear, I never downloaded anything related to it), so I'm not necessarily heartbroken, but I'm very unsure of what happened with this.

I used Ubuntu 14.04LTS for my work computer, and I decided to run an upgrade.  When the upgrade was finished, I noticed that a lot of Ubuntu related things didn't work.  I found out I now have Trisquel GNU/Linux.

I'm guessing I should probably back-up and do a fresh install, but does anybody have any insight on how this little bit of weirdness happened?  I've never upgraded and woke up with a new distro before.

Comment: Anything here ring bells (in particular, do you have/use IceCat)? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2336038

Comment: Okay, I do, in fact, use icecat...so that could be the culprit

Comment: Actually, that doesn't help me much...my /etc/lsb-release says Trisquel...

Comment: What apt sources do you have now? Did you have Trisquel sources at some point?

Comment: I don't seem to have any Trisquel sources.